# Why is OnRowDataBound only firing for my headers and not my data rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that looks something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" 
              runat="server" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              OnRowDataBound="MyGridView_RowDataBound" >
   <asp:HyperLinkField . . . . . bla bla/>
   <asp:BoundField . . . . . . . bla bla/>
</asp:GridView>
```

My event handler (MyGridView_RowDataBound) effectively looks like this:

```
protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     return;

   // do stuff here
}
```

For some reason, my code never reaches the '// do stuff here' line.  It doesn't get past the data row check, because `OnRowDataBound` is only firing for my header rows.

I have verified that data rows get created by using a `MyGridView_RowCreated` handler.  It is also obvious that the binding is taking place because when I run the website I can see the rows from my database showing up.  On top of that, I have verified that the `MyGridView.DataBind()` statement is running.

What have I overlooked that is causing my event handler to not fire for data rows?

**EDIT:** Upon further inspection, it looks like the `GridView.DataBound` event isn't firing at all, so I can't use `DataBound` and then loop through the rows.

Answer (score 1):

There was an exception occurring deep within the code that was being caught during the binding process.  Because the binding did not finish completely, `OnRowDataBound` was never called for any of the data rows.  The reason it seemed like the binding completed successfully was because all the cells that I expected to have results had them (because the binding was partially complete), and the problematic cells didn't have results as expected.  After fixing this exception, `OnRowDataBound` fired as expected for each data row.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Could you elaborate on what was causing the binding to be partially complete. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make it **==**  now this will fire for datarow

`if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)`

Alternative way loop over gridview row

```
foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows)
 {
    // do stuff here
    string value = oItem.Cells[0].Text;

 }
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how using == will make a difference.  The problem is that OnRowDataBound doesn't even get called for any data rows in the first place.

I could possibly try your second solution using the OnDataBound event handler and see if that works.  But I'd prefer doing it with OnRowDataBound, because this is a 'per row' operation.  I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: @Dalal|: best practise is to convert GirdView `boundField`  into `templateField`n also  can you provide your On_pageLoad code ?