# OnRowDatabound method doesn't execute

Tags: c#, .net

I have a GridView that modifies the CSS under certain conditions. Works fine in Development but doesn't seem to execute on the server.

.net 4.0

Ideas?

GridView:

```
GridView ID="gridViewCalendar" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
CssClass="calendarGrid" 
OnRowDataBound="GridViewCalendar_RowDataBound">
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gridViewCalendar.DataBind();
        }
}


protected void GridViewCalendar_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string b0field = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        string b1field = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;

        if (b0field == "&nbsp;")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.FromName("#C0C0C0");
            e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.FromName("#C0C0C0");
        }

        else if (b1field != "&nbsp;")
        {
            e.Row.CssClass = "calendarNormal";
        }

        else
        {
            e.Row.CssClass = "calendarBold";
        }
    } 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you put breakpoints inside your first If statement in the event handler just to make sure It is indeed getting executed?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine locally from my IDE (VS2010). Just not on the host. None of the formatting applies - setting backcolor or applying css.

Comment: Can you check If you are getting records from the database server used by the host machine?

Comment: Yes, the databind itself works fine. Data loads correctly.

Comment: I wonder if it's not related to the order in which styling is applied once compiled.

Comment: You should also look for any exceptions as described in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12187987/255562